# Google muestra struts message key en los resultados de búsqueda

Tags: tomcat, struts, buscador

Tengo hosteado un sitio web en Internet sobre un Servidor Tomcat 7.x, utilizando Struts2 como framework MVC.
Al realizar la búsqueda en los buscadores, los textos que se muestran son las keys de los mensajes de Struts (Adjunto una imagen como ejemplo)

Entiendo que los motores de búsquedas estarían accediendo las .jsp compiladas en la carpeta /work, pero no sé como hacer para lograr que los buscadores puedan mostrar correctamente los mensajes en sus resultados búsquedas.
¿Necesito realizar alguna configuración en Struts o es un problema de Tomcat?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo me dice que tu aplicación no se está ejecutando bien en producción. No me parece problema del browser sino de tu aplicación o de tu Tomcat.

Comment: Si, yo creo lo mismo. El problema es que no logro detectar cuál es el problema ya que al sitio se puede acceder correctamente y los mensajes se ven de manera correcta en las páginas. El problema es cuando los motores de búsqueda acceden para obtener la información a indexar =(

Answer (score 0):

Listo!
Problema resuelto. Era un tema con el Locale

Comment: Hola @mdigitales. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so] y gracias por tu aporte! Sería genial si pudieses ampliar sobre el motivo de tu problema y cómo lo solucionaste. De esa forma, un futuro lector con tu mismo problema sabría cómo encararlo (actualmente está poco claro, por lo que no esto no representa una respuesta de calidad). Gracias